# Working with cell addresses in excel with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a Excel sheet in which are multiple forms. The forms look all the same and they have exact the same cells between them. They are ordered in 4 x 3:

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x

x x x x
....
```

There are 60 of them and after three columns are two cells between them instead of one.

Now my question.

If I have the upper left corner address of the first form how can I "generate" the next address of the next form?

From the first upper left corner to the next is a space of 9 fields. From the first upper left corner of the first form to the next form at the bottom there are 17 fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OFFSET function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/offset-function-HP010342739.aspx)

OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

- Reference    Required. The reference from which you want to base the offset. Reference must refer to a cell or range of adjacent cells; otherwise, OFFSET returns the #VALUE! error value.
- Rows    Required. The number of rows, up or down, that you want the upper-left cell to refer to. Using 5 as the rows argument specifies that the upper-left cell in the reference is five rows below reference. Rows can be positive (which means below the starting reference) or negative (which means above the starting reference).
- Cols    Required. The number of columns, to the left or right, that you want the upper-left cell of the result to refer to. Using 5 as the cols argument specifies that the upper-left cell in the reference is five columns to the right of reference. Cols can be positive (which means to the right of the starting reference) or negative (which means to the left of the starting reference).

[EDITED] If you have merged cells, you can consider to use MergedArea (VBA) like this:

```
Set MA = Range("G14").MergeArea
NewAddress = MA.Offset(...)
```

Comment: Okay that's the right function. But since I have some merged cells in the sheet the function behaves strange. So the offset to the first cell is only 4 but it should be 9 and for the second cell it is 13 but it should be 18. Is there a flag to get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Yes, in VBA you can mark the merged area with "MergedArea" - I have edited my answer